# How to use CPackDeb?

Tags: 16.04, cmake

I am creating a .deb package with CMake/CPack. Basically it works OK, but no CPackDeb specific strings are set. CPackDeb requires that it should be called from Cpack. If I copy code to my CMakeFiles.txt,
everything works. Shall I explicitly include CPackDeb? or put it in a cmake/ directory? And place int before CPack or before package-related stuff?